# How to integrate ASP.NET 5 with signalr

Tags: signalr, asp.net5

I'm trying to make an ASP.NET 5 web app using SignalR. I've created an empty web app, I've added an index.html page with some contents but I can't integrate SignalR. So far, in order to use SignaR, I've carried out the following step:

1) I've added the following dependency in the project.json file:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc1-final"
```

2) In the Startup class, I've added

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

to the ConfigureServices method, and

```
app.UseSignalR();
```

to the Configure method.

3) I've added to the project a class deriving from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub and inserted a public method into it.

After this, in index.html I've added the logic trying to access the method but when I launch the app firefox console says

> Error: $ is not defined

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller("myctr", function ($scope) {
            $scope.input = "";
            $scope.output = "";
            $.connection.myHub1.client.JSMet1 = function (x) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.output = x;
                });
            };
            $scope.AggiornaTesto = function () {
                $.connection.myHub1.server.cSMet1($scope.input);
            };
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see I also use AngulaJS.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that I'm missing a reference to jquery-signalr. But how can I add jquery-signalr to by project?

Comment: can you post the javascript from index.html?

Answer (score 0):

> Error: $ is not defined

Its because you haven't added `jQuery` reference to your page, please read [this article from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc), it will step by step demonstrate you how to implement `SingnalR` with `ASP.NET MVC` projects.

Comment: I have already done that tutorial and it properly works with ASP.NET 4.6.1. The problem is that now I'm using ASP.NET 5 and it's totally different.

Comment: So, whats problem for now?

Comment: The problem is that even if I run "install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" in the Package Manager Console it doesn't install what is required.

Comment: Try to use `Manage NuGet Packages..` user interface, then search for SignalR and install it.